# DeadLock on Azure SQL Database without transactions

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, deadlock, database-deadlocks

It seems like despite the fact we're not using transactions at all we get random deadlock error from SQL Azure.

Are there no transnational situation when SQL Azure can get into a deadlock?

It seems like when we are running a batch of UPDATE queries it acts like the  batch is a one big transaction.

All the updates are by id and update a single a line.

Comment: I don't think that not using transactions will reduce the risk of a dead lock. I think you should provide some more detail.

Comment: How come non-transaction parallel queries can get into a deadlock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such things as "not using transactions". There's always a transaction, wether you start one explicitly or not. Read [Tracking down Deadlocks in SQL Database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqldatabasetalk/archive/2013/05/01/tracking-down-deadlocks-in-sql-database.aspx) for how to obtain the deadlock graph in SQL Azure. Connect to `master` and run:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.event_log
WHERE database_name like '<your db name>'
AND event_type = 'deadlock';
```

Then analyze the deadlock graph do understand the cause. Most likely you're doing scan because of missing indexes.

Comment: You may also include locks in your answer. Which is what actually causes the deadlocks. Table hints (WITH NOLOCK) would solve most issues (and READ UNCOMMITED). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: @RicardoC no, dirty reads are absolutely not the answer. [Dirty reads return incorrect data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx).

Comment: @RicardoC if you want to eliminate deadlocks w/o understanding the cause use snapshot isolation. Eg. read [Deadlocked!](http://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/)

Comment: Dirty reads removes the locking issues. As to being 'absolutely'... anything... no solution would be absolutely right or wrong. because... well nor you or me, understand his need, cause, or his application for that matter, because the ambiguity of the OP and his lack of understanding of transactions. And yes, I am aware of the consequences of dirty read, and how irrelevant it can be (not in an absolute sense).

Comment: I was under the impression that SQL Server is using READ COMMITTED isolation level by default for non transnational SELECT queries.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I think you're right we didn't have an index on "id" field we used for the update, thanks!

Comment: Sql DB has  RCSI enabled and be default transaction isolation level is set to this ..

Comment: @RemusRusanu I was happy to fast the index didn't solve it

Comment: @GuyKorland capture and attach the deadlock XML

Comment: @RemusRusanu deadlock XML?

Comment: Read the article I linked

Comment: @RemusRusanu I did but I'm getting "Error: Invalid object name 'sys.event_log'." when running on SQL Azure

Answer (score 2):

When you have concurrent transactions running (either implicit or explicit) you encounter deadlocks. Probably when you you said no transactions that means your transactions are implicit.

Comment: How can a batch of single UPDATE by ID can cause a deadlock? Does SQL Azure run a batch of updates as an implicit transaction?